# Recursively delete files named `log` under multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, delete-file

I have a folder structure like the below:

```
feat1
feat2
feat3
```

Now within each folder we have another folder called `builds`.
Under `builds` we have numbered folders like `1`, `2`, etc.
Under each numbered folder we have files of the pattern `*.log` and then a particular file with the name `log`.

I need to run a command in the linux server / unix server to recursively delete only the file with the name `log` not the `*.log` for all these folders `feat1`, `feat2` and `feat3`. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you run depends on how careful you want to be about your search criteria and whether you need to search recursively.

- Delete anything named `log` under `feat*/builds/*/`:

  ```
  rm feat*/builds/*/log
  ```
- Recursively find and delete anything named `log` anywhere under the current directory:

  ```
  find . -name log -delete
  ```
- Recursively find and delete anything named `log`, only under `feat*`:

  ```
  find feat* -name log -delete
  ```
- Recursively find and delete anything named `log`, only under `feat*/builds/*/`:

  ```
  find feat*/builds/*/ -name log -delete
  ```
- Recursively find and delete any *file* named `log`, only under `feat*/builds/*/`:

  ```
  find feat*/builds/*/ -name log -type f -delete
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty solution using a for loop that should get the job done.

```
for f in `find feat* -name 'log'`; do rm "$f"; done;
```

`for f in` is saying we're going to do a for loop with `f` as the variable for each result.

`find feat* -name 'log'` searches through any directory starting with "feat" with * as a wildcard.

`-name` says we're looking for a file name of `log`.

`do rm "$f"` removes each result that was found.

Sometimes it is helpful to use `echo` before doing destructive commands this way. See below.

```
for f in `find feat* -name 'log'`; do echo "$f"; done;
```